# Java FXML dynamically load content onto multiple different tabs

Tags: java, javafx, tabs, fxml, fxmlloader

I have multiple lists which I would like to loop through and return all their items in their respective tabs as buttons, each having an action.

I have tried the following:

```
@FXML
private Tab aTab;
```

And then on button press:

```
StackPane tab = new StackPane();
    tab.setStyle("-fx-background-color: Green");
    Label text = new Label("titleLabel");
    text.setStyle("-fx-font-size: 25px;");
    tab.getChildren().add(text);

    aTab.setContent(tab);
```

The immediate problem is that I get the exception

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException...
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
... 52 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException 
at (the method I'm calling aTab.setContent(tab) in
...
```

And the slightly more insidious problem is that, as the amount of tabs grow, my code is going to get increasingly bloated.

Ideally, there would be a way to display the content on each tab using a general tab xml file but I have been unable to put something like this together.

How can this be done? ***Can*** this be done?

Comment: You want to use a design pattern to controle the entropy of your code. You can look into "Model-View-Controller Pattern" for that. You can create your Views (fxml Files) with a programe like Scene Builder and then seperate these view files from the Model and Controller part. You can then create a controller for every different tab.

Comment: You should be looking at the whole stacktrace, not just the first line. The actual Exception causing the error is not the one you posted.

Comment: Also, see my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53453630/javafx-reusable-fxml-snippets/53455765#53455765); it demonstrates one way to reuse an FXML layout in multiple Tabs.

Comment: @Zephyr my bad, I read the whole thing but forgot to post it. I have edited my post to include the relevant items

Comment: You could define your FXML up to the Tab container and then use java code to create the tabs within the container.

Comment: I was able to solve this with a combination of following Zephyr's answer and combing through my main fxml manually to assign ids to the tabs. Apparently scenebuilder was originally unable to. Thanks!