# JavaFX: Identical tabs with different data

Tags: java, javafx, tabs, scenebuilder

In Lazarus, there are 2 different kinds of tab elements (cf. [Free Pascal docs](https://wiki.freepascal.org/TTabControl)):

### `TPageControl`

> `TPageControl` is a multi-page component that provides a container to hold a variety of controls per page.

### `TTabControl`

> It is a tabbed container component which looks identical to a TPageControl. However, there is a fundamental difference because the control always shows the same page whichever tab is selected. In fact, it containts only a single page. The idea behind this concept is illustrated best by an editor or viewer for text files: When the TabControl contains a TMemo then the individual tabs refer to the files loaded into the memo; whenever the active tab changes another file is loaded into the (same) memo.

In this sense, JavaFX `TabPane`s are quite similar to `TPageControl`s, but I rather want to replicate a `TTabControl`. I know I could in fact programmatically create a `new Tab()`, but I want to visually design it in SceneBuilder.

Is there maybe a way to load a separate `.fxml` file into a `new Tab()` element which is then added to the `TabPane`? (And how could I then access a tab's children?)

Comment: Knowing javafx, I think your best shot is to create the controls and update its content when (toggle/group)buttons are pressed, rather than creating a new `Container` type. Those buttons you can place at the top and style them like they are tabs, nobody will notice the difference I think.

Comment: I mean, I could also add a “head-less” `TabPane` that itself doesn't have any content and is only used to notice when the user switches between tabs. The elements that appear as the tab's content would be placed outside the `TabePane`.

Comment: Can also work. Might be less styling work as well. You could simply bind/add a changeListener to the `tabpane.getSelectionModel().selectedIndexProperty()` and update things from there.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the purpose of a `TTabControl`. What does it mean by "same page"? Does that mean the exact same view is displayed in each tab, or that different _instances_ of the same view are in each tab? To ask another way, if the view contained a text field, and you typed into it, would every tab show the same text, or only the one specific tab that you typed in?

Comment: When there's a control element in the `TTabControl`, then it's the exact same object for all tabs. It's not just an instance or clone of the element, but the actual original one.

Comment: One approach is examined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53453630/230513); more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavafx%5D+reuse+fxml).

Comment: I suppose, as I think n247s is suggested, you could observe the [selected tab](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/18/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/TabPane.html#selectionModelProperty) and set its `content` to the desired `Node`, but note that a `Node` can only appear once in the entire scene graph. If you add a `Node` to a _second_ parent, then it will typically be silently removed from it's current parent. This means the same `Node` cannot appear in multiple `Tab`s simultaneously, though that may not matter to you since only a single `Tab` is displayed in a `TabPane` at once.

Comment: However, it would be better, in my opinion, to create _separate instances_ of the view, so that each `Tab` has its own individual content. Then you could share a single _model_ instance between all views, so that a change in the model is reflected in each view.

Comment: sounds like a xy-problem (the variant trying to apply concepts from one framework into another) - so what do you _really_ want to achieve and why is that not possible with Tab/Pane, best explained with a [mcve] please

Comment: *”Is there a way to load a separate `.fxml` file into a `new Tab()` element which is then added to the `TabPane`?”*. Yes, just do it; it’s not clear what the problem with this approach is. *”And how could I then access a tab’s children”*. You can access them in the controller for the “separate” FXML file you create.

Comment: This sounds like the Tabs are actually RadioButtons masquerading as Tabs.  You can do this with styling.  Then have the OnAction for each RadioButton load different data into the Nodes in the content Pane.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I chose the [easiest approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73346140/javafx-identical-tabs-with-different-data?noredirect=1#comment129529030_73346140): Implementing a head-less `TabPane` to detect when the user switches between tabs. The elements that appear to the user as the “tab content” are actually placed outside the `TabPane`, and their content is dynamically changed whenever the tab is switched.

Comment: This seems like the _harder_ approach to me, as you seem to be fighting against the JavaFX framework (though maybe you're not; it's hard to tell without actual code).